# jQuery click doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem with nested divs, and jQuery's click function.
Clicking on .header-fb, .header-twitter or .header-linkedin don't give any results. No errors in console. I'm not sure what's going on. These classes have background image, not sure, if that makes problem too. Here's the code:

```
<div>
 <div id="header-social" class="four columns mobile-two">
 <div class="header-fb"><a href="http://www.facebook.com" >&nbsp</a></div>
 <div class="header-twitter"><a  href="https://twitter.com" >&nbsp</a></div>
 <div class="header-linkedin"><a  href="http://www.linkedin.com/">&nbsp</a></div>
</div>
```

and javascript:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function() {
            jQuery(".header-fb").click(function(){
                  window.location=jQuery(this).find("a").attr("href");
                  return false;
            });
            jQuery(".header-twitter").click(function(){
                window.location=jQuery(this).find("a").attr("href");
                return false;
            });
            jQuery(function() {
                jQuery('.header-linkedin').click(function(){
                    window.location=jQuery(this).find("a").attr("href");
                    return false;
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Do you have an `$('a').click()` listener elsewhere that's stopping the event from propagating?  A fiddle would be helpful.

Comment: Why reinventing the wheel?

Comment: Oh, and you might want some text in the links... `&nbsp` is invalid (you want `&nbsp;` for a space).  And you're missing a closing `</div>` for `#header-social`.

Comment: @NRohler no, there is no $('a').click() listener, at least I don't see it. You're right about #header-socia, it was typo.

Comment: All you do here is expand the default behavior from the a element to the parent div. Why not put the div in the link and use the default browser functionality? E.g. `<a href="http://www.facebook.com" ><div class="header-fb"></div></a>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IF your HTML should look like this:

```
<div id="header-social" class="four columns mobile-two">
   <div class="header-fb"><a href="http://www.facebook.com" >&nbsp</a></div>
   <div class="header-twitter"><a  href="https://twitter.com" >&nbsp</a></div>
   <div class="header-linkedin"><a  href="http://www.linkedin.com/">&nbsp</a></div>
</div>
```

Than you can try with:

```
(function( $ ){  // remap $ to jQuery
  $(function(){  // DOM ready shorthand

    $('#header-social').on('click','div',function(){

       var goTo = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
       window.location = goTo ;

    });

  });
})( jQuery );
```

http://jsbin.com/uxowoj/1/edit

Comment: actually the problem was in some other div that overlays .header-social div. I found the cause. I'll mark your solution as best because of the nice example you provided.

Answer (score 0):

What about if you try:

```
$(function() {

   $(".header-fb").click(function(){
      window.location = $(this).find("a").attr("href");
   });

   $(".header-twitter").click(function(){
      window.location= $(this).find("a").attr("href");
   });

   $('.header-linkedin').click(function(){
      window.location = $(this).find("a").attr("href");
   });

});
```

You're adding an extra jQuery method at the bottom of your code (for some reason) and using a lot of long-hand syntax. You also do not need to return `false`.